# ffmpeg Convert HDR to SDR

Tags: ffmpeg

I was following [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20190722004804/https://stevens.li/guides/video/converting-hdr-to-sdr-with-ffmpeg/) to convert HDR video to SDR, but when I try to run the command that actually converts video (and not just a single frame), I get an error.

Command:

```
ffmpeg -i hdr.mp4 -vf zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,format=yuv420p -c:v hevc -crf 18 -preset slower sdr.mp4
```

When I run that I get an error:

> [AVFilterGraph @ 0x1c25380] No such filter: 'zscale'14:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
>
> Error reinitializing filters!
>
> Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
>
> Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
>
> [aac @ 0x172bcc0] Qavg: 124.200
>
> [aac @ 0x172bcc0] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
>
> Conversion failed!

Comment: As it says, your ffmpeg builds doesn't have the zscale filter. Which OS?

Comment: @Gyan Docker image. Specifically https://store.docker.com/community/images/jrottenberg/ffmpeg (ubuntu image)

Comment: Get a git build from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: From https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zscale-1, you need to build ffmpeg with https://github.com/sekrit-twc/zimg

Comment: Original guide link is dead. Archive is available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20190722004804/https://stevens.li/guides/video/converting-hdr-to-sdr-with-ffmpeg/